# python re.sub not replacing string

Tags: python

I am trying to replace the string in a file like below, but somehow its not replacing

```
my_string = "TABLE "_$deleted$73$0"" --> inside can be any number, i wanted to change like below one

replace_string = "TABLE "I01""
```

```
o = "TABLE \"_$[a-z]+*$*\""
n = "TABLE \"I01\""

re.sub (o, n, file)
```

its not replacing that string, Pls help

Regards
Kannan

Comment: are you aware that `$` means "end of string" ? you have to escape it

Comment: that's only one of the problems you're having btw

Comment: even i tried with "\$" its not working, am i missing anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use raw strings to bypass Python's escape sequences (prefix the string literal with `r`) This only bypasses Python's escape sequences, the Regex's special symbols still need to be escaped. Also, using a single quoted literal is cleaner as your pattern contains double quotation marks.

There were multiple issues with your pattern. Both the `$` symbols must be prefixed with `\`. Secondly, `[a-z]+*` has a `+` followed by a `*` which doesn't make sense, you don't need the `*`.  The following is what seems to be the pattern as per the knowledge of one of its matches:

```
o =  r'TABLE "_\$[a-z]+\$\d+\$\d+"'
```

Let me know if something is not clear. Hope this helps.